# How to delete rows with a unique ID from a panel data frame in R?

Tags: r, formatting, panel-data, rowdeleting

I have a data table containing thousands of firms that can be identified by a unique ID. It is long format data and each firm is supposed to appear twice in different years (cross-sectional time-series over two years).

However, not all firms appear in both years and I am trying to create a balanced long format panel in which only firms remain that appear in both years. How do I accomplish this?

This is an example data table to illustrate the issue:

```
example <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,2013,2016,2013,2013,2016), ncol=2)
colnames(example) <- c('id', 'year')
example.table <- data.table(example)
example.table

   id year
1:  1 2013
2:  1 2016
3:  2 2013
4:  3 2013
5:  3 2016
```

In the example, I need a code/function that lets me exclude the row of the firm with the id "2", because it has no match in 2016.
In other words: I need a code/function that compares each row with the previous & subsequent row and excludes it, if there is no match in the id column.

I have invested many hours, but appear to have reached the limits of my R knowledge and would appreciate any support. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` as below:

```
library(dplyr)
example.table %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id  year
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2013
2     1  2016
3     3  2013
4     3  2016
```

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't realize you could use `group_by` for `filter` in addition to `mutate` and `summarise`

Answer (score 1):

We create a vector of `unique` 'year' from the whole dataset, then check if `all` the values in 'nm1' are `%in%` the 'year' grouped by 'id' and subset the data.table

```
un1 <- unique(example.table$year)
example.table[, .SD[all(un1 %in% year)], id]
#   id year
#1:  1 2013
#2:  1 2016
#3:  3 2013
#4:  3 2016
```

NOTE: The OP's dataset is `data.table` and the method used is `data.table` here.  Initially, thought about using `.SD[uniqueN(year) > 1]`, but that is wrong and may not work for all cases

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` equivalent solution to @Sonny's `dplyr` solution

```
example.table[, if(.N > 1) .SD, id]

   id year
1:  1 2013
2:  1 2016
3:  3 2013
4:  3 2016
```